# How to show both message and photo to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple messaging app to send text and photo to another activity but I only know how to show the text, can you teach me how to show the photo also? I am only a new programmer and I want to learn so I hope you could help me guys :)

Here is my code on the sending activity..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_attach_pic);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_img_view);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        });

    }

    public void sendMessage (View view){
        message_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = message_text.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,message);
        startActivity (intent);
    }

    private File getFile(){
        File folder = new File("sdcard/UHelp_images");

        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        File image_file = new File(folder,"temp.jpg");
        return  image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String path = "sdcard/UHelp_images/temp.jpg";
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }
```

and this is on the receiving class...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra (MESSAGE_KEY);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: Why not just pass the path of the image to the next activity as a string like you did with the text ? You can convert your image to String then convert back to image but i wont do this because if your image is big then you will have OutOfMemory problem. So best just pass the path.

Comment: So I have to create a path for the image?

Comment: Seems like your image already has a path (location your image was stored). Im sure your images are stored somewhere in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send Image Path along with Text Message like following code :

```
public void sendMessage (View view){
        message_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = message_text.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,"sdcard/UHelp_images/temp.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(IMAGE_PATH_KEY,message);
        startActivity (intent);
    }
```

(I hard coded the Image Path , You can put your variable there)
And on Receiving activity , get that Image Path and store it as a String

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra (MESSAGE_KEY);
        String ImagePath = intent.getStringExtra (IMAGE_PATH_KEY);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
```

When you have Image Path here in receiving activity then you can follow the @Cas Answer code to set it to Corresponding ImageView using following code.

```
File imgFile = new  File(ImagePath);
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Keep Coding

Comment: Do I have to create declare another String for the photo?  I am still having problems :(

Comment: The same way you are passing your message to other activity , pass path of picture and get that path in other activity

Answer (score 1):

You should just load it from the other activity with this:

```
File imgFile = new  File("sdcard/UHelp_images/temp.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You sould pass also the `Drawable` or the `path` of the image like you did with your message with a `putExtras()` then in the other `Activity` just with the `StringKey` you'll get the `Drawable` or the `path` and you can use it as you want.

### Edit

I'm not sure if that's the correct `path` but if it is you can pass this `String` and then get the `Image` from that `path` doing this `imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));` or even you can pass that `Drawable`... and use it on the other `Activity`

```
sdcard/UHelp_images/temp.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ma'am :)

Comment: Thought u accepted my answer... but welcome anyways :)